# Error Messages are not displying in PHP for validation

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Following is the PHP code
Database file working fine.

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    $error = array();

 if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
   {
     $error[] = "Please Enter a name";
   }
  else
   {
      $fname = $_POST["fname"];
   }

    if(empty($_POST["lname"]))
     {
  $error[] = "Please Enter last name";
}
   else
     {
  $lname = $_POST["lname"];
}

    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
     {
   $error = "Enter email Id";
 }
  else
     {
   if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-        9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST["email"]))
   {
     $email = $_POST["email"];
   }
  else
   {
     $error = "Enter a vaild Email Id";
   }       
    }

   if(empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
  $error = "Enter a password";
}
   else
    {
  $password = $_POST["password"];
}

    if(!empty($error))
      {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM form (id, 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Password')  VALUES('', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$password')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   echo "Successfully Register";
  }
    else
      {
   foreach($error as $key => $values)
                  {
                    echo ' <li>' . $values . '</li>';
                  }
                echo '</ol>';
    echo "Error";
  }

     }

 ?>
```

The  above code is not displying any error messages... if i submit the form only blank page ll appear... I validate my form using above code but it is just a basic method I used and by using for each I'm displaying errors...

Comment: in half of validation you used `$error` as array and in other half you used `$error` as simple string even without concating

Answer (score 1):

the following test is wrong :

```
if(!empty($error))
```

should be :

```
if(empty($error))
```

And your SQL is wrong too... should be :

```
$sql = "Insert into form (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password)  VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$password')";
```

supposing your id field is auto-incremented

Answer (score 0):

You forget to push the errors to array. You have

`$error = "Enter a password"; //$error is no more an array. It is a string`

And must be in several places:

`$error[] = "Enter a password";`

Also, I recommend you using nested `if` statements:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
  $errors = array() ;
  if (!isset($_POST['email'])
    $errors['email'] = "No email" ;
  //And so on.

  //Then check for errors
  if (!empty($errors)){
    //proceed submission
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code, it will works fine for you.

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    $error = array();

 if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
   {
     $error[] = "Please Enter a name";
   }
  else
   {
      $fname = $_POST["fname"];
   }

    if(empty($_POST["lname"]))
     {
  $error[] = "Please Enter last name";
}
   else
     {
  $lname = $_POST["lname"];
}

    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
     {
   $error[] = "Enter email Id";
 }
  else
     {
   if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-        9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST["email"]))
   {
     $email = $_POST["email"];
   }
  else
   {
     $error[] = "Enter a vaild Email Id";
   }       
    }

   if(empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
  $error[] = "Enter a password";
}
   else
    {
  $password = $_POST["password"];
}
    if(count($error)<=0)
      {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM form (id, 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Password')  VALUES('', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$password')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   echo "Successfully Register";
  }
    else
      {
   foreach($error as $key => $values)
                  {
                    echo ' <li>' . $values . '</li>';
                  }
                echo '</ol>';
    echo "Error";
  }
   }
 ?>
```